# Given an array A of N elements. A majority element in an array A of size N is an element that appears more than N/2 times in the array, a gfg question

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have tried the below python code...and I think I did it right but at the time of submitting it failed a test case saying **"Your program took more time than expected. Expected Time Limit : 2.32sec**.....**what else I can do?**

```
def majorityElement(self, A, N):
    #Your code here
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] not in d.keys():
            d[A[i]] = 1
        else:
            d[A[i]] += 1
    
    for key,val in d.items():
        if val >N/2:
            return key
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def majorityElement(self, A, N):

        d = [0]*1000005 # Instead of a dict, initialize an array of size 10^6 + 1 because all Ai <= 10^6
        for i in range(N):
            d[A[i]] += 1
            if d[A[i]] > N/2: 
                return A[i]
        return -1
```